# Set on mysql only with one running schema

Tags: mysql, database

Can anyone help me to set up a mysql database only with one schema?
I tried to reset root password to database, but while switching on mysqld I've got an error that mysqld is ended. 
I tried to change my.cnf etc. but I have no time to tries because shop is still running on this database so I shouldn't switching down a database.
Ones upon a time I was reseting a root password but then I had no problems with it. I'm thinking that InnoDB could be main problem on mysql because I had some errors on logs while I tried to set up mysqld with --skip-grant-tables and --skip-networking. I would like to start mysqld only with main mysql schema running but I can not Google any tutorials for that. Do anyone know how to do this? That could be easier and faster then trying to set up my.cnf correctly for mysqld. I spend few hours on that and I have no f**king idea what am I doing wrong?! (switching off innodb on my.cnf doesn't  helped me - I tried) I'm thinking about dump all databases and reinstall mysql on Ubuntu but it sucks... (I have access but not by root)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //get it using DATABASE() function -

 SELECT DATABASE();

// set it using USE statement -

 USE database1;
```

Comment: set default database every time using USE database or connection string